# Find the solution of binary xor operator equation

Tags: matrices, binary, gaussian-elimination

I am working in binary xor operator $\mathbb Z_2$. I have to resolve my problem such as
$$\begin {cases}
x_1+x_2+x_3=1\\
x_1+x_2=0\\
x_1+x_3=1\\
\end {cases}$$

Could you suggest to me any method to find the solution. I hear that gaussian elimination is one option. How about the other solution?
Solution for this equation is 
$$x_1=0,x_2=0,x_3=1$$
For more complex equation 
$$\begin {cases}
x_1+x_2=0\\
x_2+x_3=1\\
x_3+x_4=1\\
\end {cases}$$
In this case we can see we have only 3 equation but we must find 4 variances. The solution is
$$x_1=0;x_2=0; x_3=1, x_4=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitution works fine.  Plug your second into the first to get $x_3=1$ and so on.  Another ways is that the second gives you $x_1=x_2$ and you can plug that in to eliminate one of the variables.

Comment: Milikan: Thank for quick reply. However, I am working in matrix. My equation look like $Gx$ in which G=[1 1 1;1 1 0; 1 0 1]. Is it no problem when I formula?

Comment: I like the idea $x_1=x_2$. Do you know any algorithm to find the solution of it?How about the more complex equation in my question

Comment: When solving simultaneous equations by substitution, you try to form equations of the sort (one variable)=(some expression in the other variables).  Then you plug that expression in everywhere the variable occurs.  $x_1=x_2$ is in that form, so replace $x_1$ by $x_2$ everywhere it appears.  You are now down to two variables instead of three.  Gaussian elimination is one way of organizing this, it is really doing the same thing.  There is only one solution, just different routes to get there.

Comment: For your second set, $x+4$ is only in the last, so ignore it until the end.  Add the middle two, remembering that $1+1=0, x_3+x_3=0$, and you have $x_1+x_2=0, x_1=x_2$  I don't understand "Do you know any algorithm to find the solution of it?How about the more complex equation in my question" at all.  It is an equation, one step along the way to the solution.

Comment: SOrry, I mistake the equation. I update it. The complex that mean we have the number of equation is small than the number of variances that we must find

Comment: With fewer equations than unknowns you don't have a unique solution.  For the new set, $x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=0,x_4=1$ is also a solution.  Since you have exactly two variables on each left side, if you negate all the variables you don't change the value, so it is easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for *any* method, I will add that making an exhaustive search for a solution is perfectly viable here. For the first exercise, you only have $2^3=8$ cases to try and in the second $2^4=16$.

It may not be as elegant or give as much insight and understanding, but sometimes it's the most practical way to go.